# How can you interpret the Schrödinger equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, time-evolution

When you look at the abstract Schrödinger equation
$$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\Psi\rangle=\hat H|\Psi\rangle$$
you can interpret it in two ways (I think) depending on what you consider known. It could either define how states evolve in time given that you know the Hamiltonian or it could define the Hamiltonian given that you know the time evolution of a state. So to put it in words, which of these two is more accurate?

1. We know the Hamiltonian, it is an operator that tells us about the energy content of a state. The Schrödinger equation then amazingly tells us that it also describes how states evolve in time.
2. We know how states evolve in time. The Schrödinger equation tells us that this acts like a linear operator. We name this operator *the Hamiltonian* and interestingly this operator is related to energy.

---

EDIT: To clarify I'm not interested in the opinion-side of this question, I'm interested in how the Schrödinger equation is used in practice and what it tells us about the universe like @Andrew mentioned

Comment: why should one of the option exclude the other?

Comment: The Hamiltonian is a generator of time translations. So, can't we say that Schrödinger's equation is an expression that relates how the time translations take place with a certain Hamiltonian?

Comment: For what it's worth I think there is a good question here (I didn't vote to close). As a friendly suggestion, perhaps the "opinion-based" criticism can be addressed by rephrasing the question as something like "can you use the Schrodinger equation to solve for $H$, $\psi$, both, or neither, and at a high level how do you solve it?"

Comment: "You don't know" how a state evolves. You typically know how the shape of the Hamiltonian and then the time-evolution is found by solving the equation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An equation doesn't tell you what is known or unknown. All an equation can do is tell you that two quantities, that could logically have been different, actually have the same value.

Having said that, it's possible to use the Schrodinger equation, plus other information, to determine the state or determine the Hamiltonian. In my experience, it's much more common and much easier to start from some known (or at least guessed) Hamiltonian and derive the states. In this case, the mathematical problem is to solve an eigenvalue problem for $H$.

In the other direction: at least in the stationary case, if $H=p^2/2m + V$, then going from stationary states back to inferring the potential is known as the *inverse scattering problem*, and is extremely difficult in general. A poetic name for this problem is ["can you hear the shape of a drum"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_the_shape_of_a_drum); in general the answer to the question is "no" in the sense that knowing the spectrum of an operator (ie, the frequencies of the eigenmodes) does not uniquely determine that operator. Having said that, people do learn interesting things by studying this problem; for example it is the basis of x-ray crystallography.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It doesn't exactly answer my question but it still gives insight

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion Is it possible to give a bit more idea of what it would help to expand on to get closer to your question?

Comment: In terms of "what does it tell us about the Universe," I think an accurate statement is that the Schrodinger equation says in that states evolve continuously in time, and in an infintesimally small time interval the difference between an initial and final state is determined by a linear **Hermitian** operator applied to the initial state (Hermitian is the key word -- there are times you can use non-Hermitian Hamiltonians, but only as an approximation if you ignore some of the degrees of freedom in the system). You can *use* this information in different ways, depending on what else you know.